# Laravel - Advanced Sum Aggregate in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this table in mysql:

> student_payment : id, student_class(varchar), student_code(varchar), gender(varchar), amount(float), created_at (timestamp)

Model name is is StudentPayment

What I want to achieve is that:

1. If student_class is JSS1, it checks the amount paid by each gender and place it in the respective column
2. If student_class is JSS2, it checks the amount paid by each gender and place it in the respective column
3. If student_class is SSS1, it checks the amount paid by everyone, both male and female
4. If student_class is SSS2, it checks the amount paid by everyone, both male and female
5. It sums everything vertically and horizontally
6. It groups everything by date (created_at)

I have this query in my **Controller**, but don't know how to continue

```
    $students = DB::table('student_payment')
    ->select(
       'student_class', 
       'gender',
       'amount',
      DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as created_date')
  )               
 ->orderByRaw('created_at DESC');
```

The result I want to achieve is as shown below:

[image: expected_result]

How do I complete this query in the controller to achieve this result.  Thanks

Comment: You have manipulate the php array, with only database query it seems too much complex

Comment: What do I do? And how do I write the query

Comment: At first, just take all necessary data and using loops you can calculate totals as you necessary

Comment: Plase can you give me a sample

Answer (score 0):

Following Code will give you grouping of student payment data,

```
    $payments = DB::table('student_payment')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

    $data = [];
    foreach ($payments as $payment){
        if($payment->gender=="male"){
            $data[$payment->student_class]['male'][] = $payment->amount;
        }elseif($payment->gender=="female"){
            $data[$payment->student_class]['female'][] = $payment->amount;
        }
    }
```

Now you can calculate the sum of amounts using array_sum function. For example,

If you want to calculate payment of JSS1 class female student then,

```
array_sum(data['JSS1']['female']);
```

This will give the sum of payment. You can calculate like this for other as well.